# How to multiply D with Y (HCS12)

Tags: assembly, multiplication

I don't know how to do this, I tried to find the source in the instruction set but i didn't find it.
I'm sorry if I said something bad, I'm new with the assembly language and my english isn't so good.

Comment: What's wrong with the `MUL` instruction?

Comment: @dovetalk, it's 8-bit, and multiplies accumulator A by accumulator B.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EMUL` or `EMULS`, depending on whether the values are signed.

See the [S12CPUV2 Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/S12CPUV2.pdf) for details.